# gwt error :component not available

Tags: gwt

anyone know what is error triggered from in gwt?

```
[Exception... "Component is not available" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/components/nsSessionStore.js :: sss_saveState :: line 1909" data: no]
getLabels()(Object t=Object name=iw, Object, "http://gg.google.com/csi")NmZDK%2B...oNg%3D%3D (line 1)
Lz("iw", [["iwo0", 0 0=iwo0 1=0], ["oss0", 3141 0=oss0 1=3141], ["oss1", 3910 0=oss1 1=3910], 1 more... 0=[2] 1=[2] 2=[2] 3=[2]], Object)NmZDK%2B...oNg%3D%3D (line 1)
Qz("iw", [["iwo0", 0 0=iwo0 1=0], ["oss0", 3141 0=oss0 1=3141], ["oss1", 3910 0=oss1 1=3910], 1 more... 0=[2] 1=[2] 2=[2] 3=[2]], Object)NmZDK%2B...oNg%3D%3D (line 1)
Pz("iw")NmZDK%2B...oNg%3D%3D (line 1)
wl()()main.js (line 1018)
require()()main.js (line 165)
XA()("stats", 1, function(), undefined, undefined)main.js (line 162)
require()("stats", 1, function(), undefined, undefined)main.js (line 166)
Rc("stats", 1, function(), undefined, undefined)main.js (line 175)
wl("iw", [["iwo0", 0 0=iwo0 1=0], ["oss0", 3141 0=oss0 1=3141], ["oss1", 3910 0=oss1 1=3910], 1 more... 0=[2] 1=[2] 2=[2] 3=[2]], Object)main.js (line 1018)
mh()(["iw", [["iwo0", 0 0=iwo0 1=0], ["oss0", 3141 0=oss0 1=3141], ["oss1", 3910 0=oss1 1=3910], 1 more... 0=[2] 1=[2] 2=[2] 3=[2]], Object 0=iw 1=[4] 2=Object])main.js (line 297)
fh()()main.js (line 277)
p([Object gj=report ZO=0 Ea=0 __type=[4] 0=Object], function())main.js (line 102)
Q(pf(), "report")main.js (line 277)
pP()()main.js (line 1004)
branch()(undefined, undefined)main.js (line 1001)
dC()()main.js (line 1319)
O()()main.js (line 139)
Sx()()
```

Comment: What version? What brower? Web of hosted mode?

Comment: 1.64 ,firefox,not hosted mode, run in firefox, on mac

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you've compiled the application for this specific browser type.